# Accessing some data of an object inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Been looking around haven't find a solution.. Might be a really stupid question  (probably) but haven't found a way to access  to it.

I have the class Iphone:

```
export class Iphone{
    version: string;
    fixes = [
        {fixlcdprice:null},
        {fixspeakerprice:null}
    ];
}
```

then I have an array of Iphone with data

```
export const IPHONES:Iphone[]=[
{
    version:'Iphone 4',
        fixes:[
           {fixlcdprice:19},
           {fixspeakerprice:19}
       ]

},

   {


    version:'Iphone 4s',
        fixes: [
            {fixlcdprice:19},
            {fixspeakerprice:29}
        ]
}
]
```

trying to access the price of the fixes but I can't.

have tryed

```
Iphone.fixes[0]  <-- returns (object, object)
```

then tryed

```
Iphone.fixes[0[0]] <-- returns nothing..
Iphone.fixes.fixlcdprice <-- doesnt work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want

`Iphone.fixes[0].fixlcdprice`

Comment: thank you that was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
Iphone=[
{
    version:'Iphone 4',
        fixes:[
           {fixlcdprice:19},
           {fixspeakerprice:19}
       ]

},

   {


    version:'Iphone 4s',
        fixes: [
            {fixlcdprice:19},
            {fixspeakerprice:29}
        ]
}
]
```

Iphone[0].fixes[0] gives you the disired result